# How can you return Redirect using React Router?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redirect, react-router

I'm a bit of a React noob.

I'm trying to create a conditional Redirect, so have written a function (errorCapture) in which one outcome should trigger a Redirect. I'm returning the  statement back to a child component (ErrorOrReroute) within the return statement, within my functional component, in the hope that that would cause the page to change. No such luck!

- I know the route works under other circumstances.
- There is a console.log('redirect'); next to the returned  statement in the function, which is displaying as expected, so I know the function is working as intended.
- There are no other error messages in the console.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!!

(Side question: is it 'ok' to have written a component entirely inside the code for another component? WIll is work? Is it considered dirty coding, *if I can be sure it won't need to be used elsewhere*? Thanks.)

````
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import AuthContainer from './auth-container';
import { Button, Form, Message, Segment } from 'semantic-ui-react';
import { NavLink, useParams, Redirect } from 'react-router-dom';
import { withFormik } from 'formik';
import { PasswordResetConfirmService } from '../../utils/api/auth/auth.js';
import { mapFormError, NonFieldErrors } from '../../modules/forms';
import { t } from 'ttag';


let uidString = '';
let tokenString = '';
let executed = false;


const PasswordResetConfirmPage = ({ logged, values, handleChange, handleBlur, handleSubmit, isSubmitting, errors }) => {
  const { token, uid } = useParams();
  uidString = uid;
  tokenString = token;

  const ErrorOrReroute = () => {
    const errorCapture = () => {
      if (Object.keys(errors).length === 0) return false;
      if (Object.keys(errors).includes('uid') || Object.keys(errors).includes('token')) return true;
    };

    if (logged && !errorCapture()) {
      console.log('redirect');
      return <Redirect to={{ pathname: '/' }} />;
    } else if (executed && errorCapture()) {
      return (
        <Message negative>
          {'Password update failed :( Please request another password-reset email.'}
        </Message>
      );
    } else return null;
  };

  return (
    <AuthContainer title={t`Reset Password`}>

      <Form size="large" onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
        <Segment stacked>
          <Form.Input fluid icon="lock" iconPosition="left" placeholder={t`New Password`} type="password" name="new_password1" onChange={handleChange} onBlur={handleBlur} value={values.new_password1} error={mapFormError(errors, 'new_password1')} />
          <Form.Input fluid icon="lock" iconPosition="left" placeholder={t`Repeat New Password`} type="password" name="new_password2" onChange={handleChange} onBlur={handleBlur} value={values.new_password2} error={mapFormError(errors, 'new_password2')} />
          <NonFieldErrors errors={errors} />
          <Button primary fluid size="large" type="submit" loading={isSubmitting} disabled={isSubmitting} > {' '} {t`Confirm New Password`}{' '} </Button>
          <ErrorOrReroute />
        </Segment>
      </Form>

      <Message> {' '} {t`Know your password?`} &nbsp; <NavLink to="/login">{t`Login`}</NavLink>{' '} </Message>

    </AuthContainer>
  );
};

const withRegistrationErrors = withFormik({
  mapPropsToValues: () => ({ new_password1: '', new_password2: '', uid: '', token: '' }),
  handleSubmit: (values, { props, setSubmitting, setErrors }) => {
    values.uid = uidString;
    values.token = tokenString;
    executed = true;
    PasswordResetConfirmService(values)
      .then(() => {
        setSubmitting(false);
        props.toggleLoggedState();
      })
      .catch(errors => {
        setErrors(errors);
      });
  }
});

PasswordResetConfirmPage.propTypes = {
  values: PropTypes.object,
  handleChange: PropTypes.func,
  handleBlur: PropTypes.func,
  handleSubmit: PropTypes.func,
  isSubmitting: PropTypes.bool,
  errors: PropTypes.object,
  email: PropTypes.string,
  toggleLoggedState: PropTypes.func,
  logged: PropTypes.bool
};

export default withRegistrationErrors(PasswordResetConfirmPage);```
````

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend using `history` to change implement the conditional redirect here:

Do so by adding `useHistory` to your `react-router-dom` import like this:

```
import { NavLink, useParams, useHistory } from 'react-router-dom';
// You won't need Redirect anymore
```

Then under `const { token, uid } = useParams();` add this line:

```
const history = useHistory()
```

Then finally, replace `<Redirect to={{ pathname: '/' }} />` with either:

```
return history.push('/')
```

OR

```
return history.replace('/')
```

You can read up more about each of those, and decide which one depending on your future use cases, but right now either one of those options will solve your issue here.

---

Regarding your side question. What you're doing is indeed dirty coding, you should be passing variables via function parameters. Not having those values stored globally in your file like you have done now.

Comment: Thanks Barry, thanks really helpful. I'll give that stuff a try!

Comment: You're welcome, I hope it's what you need! Happy Coding :)